# React Native AsyncStorage Not Resolving

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am using asyncstorage in react native , i have followed the guide from FB. but my promise is not resoving .

```
componentDidMount() {
    async function getitem() {
      try {
        const retrievedItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
        console.log(retrievedItem);

        const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
        console.log(item);
        return item;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      return;
    }
    getitem();
  }
```

my console is like .. this...

```
 {"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null} AddUser.js:33 {_40: 0, _65: 
 0,
 _55: null, _72: null}
```

Comment: How you stored the item?

Comment: var res = await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                  "user",
                  JSON.stringify(USER)
                );
                return res;

Comment: I think this should work. You can refer it’s usage here https://github.com/SandipNirmal/React-Native-MovieDB/blob/master/src/App.js. It’s working for me

Comment: Does it return `true` when you set items? It resolves otherwise you would catch an error. Can you post what is inside the `USER` variable? Maybe the stringify method returns some weird things.

Answer (score 1):

You should return item using Promise Pattern.

try like this.

```
async function getitem() {
  try {
    const retrievedItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
    return Promise.resolve(item);
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
  // return; <-- don't need this!
}
```

And, I recommend a better react coding pattern below.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getItem("YOUR_KEY").then(response => {
    // do stuff using response ..
  });
}

async getItem(key) {
  //.. do stuff
}
```